# Dynamic Selection of Slicer for Character Values

Tags: dynamic, powerbi, slicers, default-selected

So, I have a Power BI report where I have a slicer with values such as :

```
202005
202004
202003
202002
202001
Pacing
```

Every month, the data gets added and the category is incremented by 1. i.e in June, I'll have 202006 as well.

I have a report where I want the data to be filtered by last 3 months and Pacing.

i.e in May, default selection should be 202004, 202003, 202002, Pacing

in June, default selection should be 202005,202004,202003, Pacing

In other words, I want default selection of: max month-1, max month -2, max month -3 and pacing.

Currently, I am manually making the selection and saving the report and then publishing it again. But to do so, I have to refresh data every time to get updated values of the month and it has increased my file size to a great extent because the data is imported in my report. I believe that my report can crash anytime if I continue this.

Answer (score 0):

While you [can't yet directly set slicer defaults](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/7162004-default-selected-slicer-or-tile-by-value-configura), there are [some workarounds](https://powerpivotpro.com/2018/12/setting-a-default-slicer-selection/).

However, [relative date filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/desktop-slicer-filter-date-range) or Top N filtering on a slicer might help:

[image: Top N Slicer Filter]

If you don't need all the old data, you can keep your file size from continuing to grow by filtering the dates in the query editor before they are loaded to the model.

Comment: Thank you so much for your revert. So, if I filter the slicer itself, I will loose the flexibility to view the graph for any data. I need to have all the data in the report but need to make the graph for a default view for few months. i.e if I have months : from 201909 to 202005. I need to show the graph for top few months but still I need to have the flexibility to update the graph for 201909. I hope this makes my question more clear?

Comment: The only way you can sort of set defaults is by using filters on a slicer so you can't also have all the dates showing at the same time as only the filtered dates. You have to choose some compromise to live with until Microsoft actually implements the idea I linked to (please vote for it!).

Comment: Hey, I got one answer in this post : https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Dynamic-Selection-of-Slicer-for-Character-Values/m-p/1128476#M514635

Comment: It's a clever workaround. It's still not setting default selections on the slicer but if it works for your use case, great!